# Getting the Last TD of a TR with a matching TD BS4

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<tr>
 <td>Year-End</td>
 <td>Blah</td>
 <td>Blah</td>
 <td>Blah</td>
 <td>Magic!</td>
</tr>
```

How I can I grab the last TD of any rows that have "Year-End" in them? Essentially trying to grab "Magic!" above.

I can search for "Year-End" just fine, just not sure how to iterate to the last TD of the TR that the "Year-End" TD is in.

```
tds = soup.findAll('td')

for td in tds:
    if "YEAR-END" in td.text.upper():
        print td.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works

```
tds = soup.findAll('td')[-1]
print tds.get_text()
```